# Install nodejs boilerpipe module on windows?

Tags: node.js, boilerpipe

I am trying to install node js module for boilerpipe on windows 7. But the npm result with the following error. I have installed the node-gyp as well.

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: incorrect header check
gyp ERR! stack     at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:366:17)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Projects\xyz\node_modules\boilerpipe\node_modules\java
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "boilerpipe"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! java@0.4.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.4.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the java package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls java
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```